# Como mostrar colección de botones en Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Estoy creando una tabla dinámica en **ASP.NET** con la ayuda de **Datatables** libreria de **Javascript** y **jQuery** y estoy presentando un problema al momento de utilizar la colección de botones **colvis**, esta coleccion crea un boton que cuando se active, mostrará una lista de las columnas en la tabla y proporcionará al usuario final la capacidad de alternar la visibilidad de la columna para satisfacer sus propios requisitos.

[Documentacion de colvis](https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis)

Sucede que en mi tabla no se esta cargando esa colección o no se esta mostrando, necesito hacerlo con **colvis** para permitirle al usuario ver las columnas que el decida, esto lo hago porque la tabla tiene bastantes columnas

De esta manera estoy cargando el datatable

**RecordsTable.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table=$("#recordsTable").DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": document.getElementById("table").value,
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontró nada",
            "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros",
            "emptyTable": "No hay datos para mostrar",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primera",
                "last": "Última",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            },
            //Aqui agrego la coleccion de botones
            "buttons": {                
                "colvis": "Visibilidad de columnas"
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":        "details-control",
                "orderable":        false,
                "data":             null,
                "defaultContent":   ""
            },
            { "title": "#", "data": "RecordId", "searchable": true },
            { "title": "Fecha de Registro", "data": "RecordDate", "searchable": true },
            {
                "title": "Acción", "data": "RecordAction", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData) {
                    if (oData.RecordAction === "Se han cargado archivos nuevos") {
                        $(nTd).html(`<a href="#!" onclick="filesRequest(${oData.RecordId})" data-id=${oData.RecordId}>${oData.RecordAction}</a>`);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(nTd).html(`<td>${oData.RecordAction}</td>`);
                    }
                }, "searchable": true
            },
            { "title": "Nota", "data": "RecordNote", "searchable": true },
            { "title": "Solicitante", "data": "RecordUpdate", "searchable": true },
            { "title": "Asignado", "data": "RecordAsigned", "searchable": true },
            { "title": "Estado", "data": "RecordStatus", "searchable": true }
        ],
        orderCellsTop: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: {
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    className: 'btn btn-primary',

                    init: function (api, node, config) {
                        $(node).removeClass('dt-button')
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

        

    });
    initComplete: table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo($('#recordsTable_wrapper  .col-md-6:eq(0) '));

});
```

De esta manera creo la tabla

**Index.cshtml**

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="TableDiv" class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                            <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Historial</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="recordsTable" class="display compact responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Número de Registro</th>
                                            <th>Fecha de Registro</th>
                                            <th>Solicitante</th>
                                            <th>Acción</th>
                                            <th>Nota</th>
                                            <th>Asignado</th>
                                            <th>Estado</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal con el datatable que no me esta mostrando el **colvis** o como debería de hacerlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que te falta agregar algunas librerías extras que se encuentran dentro de la librería de `Datatables` o tal vez no tengas las mas actuales.

**Por ejemplo**:  las que se llaman `dataTables.buttons`, esa es aparte de la librería llamada **`buttons.colVis`**, todas esas son necesarias para que el **`ColVis`** pueda funcionar.

Te dejo un ejemplo con datos ficticios:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100],
            [10, 25, 50, 100]
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontró nada",
            "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros",
            "emptyTable": "No hay datos para mostrar",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primera",
                "last": "Última",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            },
        },

        orderCellsTop: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        dom: 'Brtip',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'colvis',
            collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column',
            postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore']
        }]
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" valign="bottom">
                Name
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="0" class="employee-search-input">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Position
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input">
            </th>
            <th>
                City
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input">
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input">
            </th>
            <th>
                Joining date
                <br>
                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input datepicker">
            </th>
            <th>
                Salary
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Funciono perfecto me hacia falta agregar el dom